# css doesn't load with node JS server despite using express.static

Tags: css, node.js, express, static-files

It is so ridiculous but i'm stuck for days in a very meaningless code situation.

I can't have the css, the image to load on my nodejs server.

I tried many things (express.static, etc.) but nothing seems to work.

Can you help me ?

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app running on port ${port}`)
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Découvrez ma newsletter pour acquérir les bases du marketing digital et du growth. Zennit est une agence Growth spécialisée en scraping et génération de leads.">
    <title>Agence Growth - spécialité scraping et leads generation</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/web_version.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/mobile_version.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/tablet_version.css">
</head>
```

**File structure**

[image]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You aren't using `express.static()` anywhere? All you're doing is responding to **every request** with `index.html`

Comment: No i'm using it. I just did not put it on the file i delete it from app.js cause it doesn't work.

Comment: I thought it was not relevant to put it as it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To statically server your `assets` directory as `/assets`, you'll want something like this

```js
app.use("/assets", express.static(__dirname + "/assets"));
```

This means any request to `/assets/*` will serve static files from your `assets` directory, eg

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/web_version.css" />
<img src="/assets/images/some-image.png" />
<script src="/assets/js/some-frontend-script.js"></script>
```

---

You're also serving `index.html` for every single request. Change it to the following to only serve it for `GET /` or `GET /index.html`

```js
app.get(["/", "/index.html"], (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})
```

---

I'd recommend keeping all static files, including `index.html` in one directory to serve statically. For example, with this directory structure

```
app/
├─ public/
│  ├─ assets/
│  │  ├─ css/
│  │  ├─ js/
│  │  ├─ images/
│  ├─ index.html
├─ app.js
├─ package.json
```

All you'd need is

```js
app.use(express.static("public"))
```

There would be no need for `res.sendFile()` at all.

Comment: Ok cool for your insight, can you tell me how the css link should look like. I fell that I also have a problem here. As I like to learn, can you tell me more regarding the every single request. What do you mean by that ? There is something I'm missing.

Comment: @MohamedNecib `app.use((req, res, next) => { ... })` is basically [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) that runs on every request.

Comment: Ok, I've tried your solution, but can this message : Cannot GET /web_version.css I mean it is weird cause the file is there...

Comment: What does your `<link>` element look like?

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis in first code snippet ;)